# Character to Date change yields "NA" within dataframe

Tags: r

In a dataframe, there is a column with date information as character

```
str(mv$datum_mw)

 chr [1:6] "Nov 15, 2012" "Jan 28, 2013" "Aug 12, 2014" "Feb 12, 2015" "Jul 1, 2015" "Feb 9, 2016"
```

All attempts to convert this character to regular date formats yield "NA"

```
mv$new_date_column <- as.Date(mv$datum_mw, format = "%b ,%d %Y")
mv$new_date_column <- format(mv$new_date_column, "%b-%y %Y")
```

or

```
dates <- as.Date(mv$datum_mw, "%m/%d/%Y")
```

Comment: Try with `format = "%b %d, %Y"`, e.g. `as.Date("Nov 15, 2012", format = "%b %d, %Y")`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `mdy` from `lubridate`, exact format doesn't matter as long as the *month, day, year* order is kept.

```
library(lubridate)

mdy(c("Nov 15, 2012", "Jan 28, 2013", "Aug 12, 2014", "Feb 12, 2015",
 "Jul 1, 2015", "Feb 9, 2016", "031124", "01-12-89", "4/2/2011"))
[1] "2012-11-15" "2013-01-28" "2014-08-12" "2015-02-12" "2015-07-01"
[6] "2016-02-09" "2024-03-11" "1989-01-12" "2011-04-02"
```

Note: In your solution the comma is in the wrong position, see @stefans comment.